# Cannot implicitly convert type 'Systems.Collections.Generic.List C# JSON

Tags: c#, json

I'm trying to deserialize a bit of JSON but I keep getting an error on this

```
temp =  des.Deserialize<RootObject>(reponse);
```

So I add a < List > to it

```
temp =  des.Deserialize<List<RootObject>>(reponse);
```

and I get 'Cannot implicitly convert type 'Systems.Collections.Generic.List<...> to ...'

```
[ { "ID": 1, "title": "XO", "artist": "EDEN", "featuredArtist": "", "releaseYear": 2015, "album": "i think you think too much of me", "streamURL": "spotify" }, { "ID": 2, "title": "Humble", "artist": "Kendrick Lamar", "featuredArtist": "", "releaseYear": 2017, "album": "DAMN", "streamURL": "spotify" } ]
```

The JSON starts off as an array, then goes into the object

```
public class AllMusic
    {
        public List<Songs> song { get; set; }

    }

    public class RootObject
    {
        public List<AllMusic> allMusic { get; set; }
    }

    public class Songs
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public string title { get; set; }
        public string artist { get; set; }
        public string featuredArtist { get; set; }
        public int releaseYear { get; set; }
        public string album { get; set; }
        public string streamURL { get; set; }
    }
```

The reponse `var reponse = client.Execute(request);`

I'm calling it through a URL

```
var client = new RestClient("http://localhost:55889/api/music");
```

I am getting a null reponse.

Comment: we need the full message here

Comment: Can you show the JSON that you are trying to deserialize. Is it a list, is it an array, is it a single object, etc.  Also, can you show the complete error that you are getting. As the question stands now it will be hard to answer without just blind guessing. See [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Not nearly enough info.  Please read [ask] and take the [tour]

Comment: How does `reponse` looks like ? How does the `RootObject` definition looks like ?

Comment: You need to post your JSon and Object.. then We can help you.. without this info it's impossible to understand the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your JSON string is for an array of Songs's. So you should try to deserialize to that

```
 var songs = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Songs>>(reponse);
```

Assuming `reponse` is a string which has the JSON string you have in your question

Comment: Still getting the same error

Comment: What is the type of the result `client.Execute(request);` ? Is it the JSON String ? If yes, it should work

Comment: Share the code related to what is `client` and how you are calling the web api to get this json string

Comment: `var reponse = client.Execute(request);`
I'm calling it through a URL
`var client = new RestClient("http://localhost:55889/api/music");`

Comment: You still did not answer the question ! What is the type of `response` ? The code should work if the value in that variable is the exact json string you posted in the question. It will be helpful to know what is `client` and what does `Execute` method returns. Put a breakpoint in your code and inspect what is coming back from `Execute` method, the type & or the value

Comment: Getting a null reponse

Comment: There you go ! You need to fix that. We cannot tell you how to fix it because we do not know what the Execute method on your client object do. To prevent the error. You can do a null check on the response before trying to deserialize.

Comment: Cheers.Thaks for the help

Comment: @Christopher - demo of `Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Songs>>(reponse);` working with the specified JSON string here: https://dotnetfiddle.net/zMlEcW.

Comment: @dbc Thats got it working now thanks!